# Python - How do I add an offset factor to a text file?

Tags: python, encryption, ascii, offset

I have code that converts a text file into ASCII characters and creates a random offset factor via 8 generated numbers. I now need to use that offset factor to convert the file and encrypt it. My question is how?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can improve your chances of getting the answer you need by improving your question. What have you tried so far? What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your actual output? What, if any errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably add more info to your question, but maybe this can get you started. To convert a letter to its ASCII integer value, use ord:

```
print ord('a')
```

To convert an integer to its corresponding ASCII letter (if the integer is in the ASCII range) use chr:

```
print chr(97)
```

An example might be:

```
def GetOffSet(letter):
    return 17  # we don't know how you are creating your offset

message = 'i like turtles'
encrypted_message = ''.join([ chr(ord(letter)+GetOffSet(letter)) for letter in message ])
decrypted_message = ''.join([ chr(ord(letter)-GetOffSet(letter)) for letter in encrypted_message ])
print decrypted_message
```

But there is a danger that your offset will push the integer outside the ASCII range, you will need someway to prevent/deal with that.